# without leave focus from control data not saved

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have field on my project product form Price Per Unit when enter some value in textbox and without tab out click on save button, data is getting saved.

[image]

But when i have done the same thing with my custom save button that value doesn't save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by following code :

```
if ($(“input[attrname='[field_logicalname]'”).length > 0 && $(“input[attrname='[field_logicalname]'”) != '') {
           Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“[field_logicalname]”).setValue($(“input[attrname='[field_logicalname]'”).val());
}
```

[Check the full discription here : debajitcrm.wordpress.com](https://debajitcrm.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/not-getting-latest-crm-text-field-value-on-click-of-custom-ribbon-button-in-crm-2013/#comments)

Answer (score 0):

Data changes when controls lose focus, I managed to solve the same issue through `HTMLElement.blur()`

As in:

```
// This should be the first thing to do in custom-saving code
var elid = document.activeElement.id;
if (elid && elid != null && elid != '') 
    document.activeElement.blur();
```

This is **unsupported by CRM** but should work in all major *desktop* browsers.

Comment: @Alex-elid gives me blank even if i don't move tab from textbox.